# How can I make an IDerefable in clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is there a way to make another container in cljs like it is in clojure by implementing IDeref?

```
(reify clojure.lang.IDeref
     (deref [_] ...))
```

The compiler warns IDeref is not a protocol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
(def a
  (reify IDeref
    (-deref [_] "Hello!")))

(.log js/console @a)
```

outputs "Hello!". You may want to use deftype:

```
(deftype LikeAtom []
  IDeref
  (-deref [_] "Hello!"))

(.log js/console @(LikeAtom.))
```